# New-Object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.DomainFederationSettings]: verify that the assembly

Tags: azure, powershell, ws-federation

I am following documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/direct-federation on Powershell and running below command:

```
Import-Module AzureAD
Connect-AzureAD
$federationSettings = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.DomainFederationSettings
```

**I am getting following error:**

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $federationSettings = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.DomainFederationSettings


New-Object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.DomainFederationSettings]: verify that the assembly 
containing this type is loaded.
At line:1 char:23
+ ... nSettings = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.DomainFederationS ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

[DomainFederationSettings class seems to be missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/249hM.png)

How can I have Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.DomainFederationSettings loaded and execute command `$federationSettings = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.DomainFederationSettings`

Answer (score 2):

at the time of writing this answer, you need to use **AzureADPreview** module and not **AzureAd**

I highly suspect you are trying this statement with the latter rather than the former.

To install

```
Install-Module -Name AzureADPreview -AllowClobber
```

(`-AllowClobber` is to allow the installation side-to-side with **AzureAD** module, if you have it installed)

> **To configure direct federation in Azure AD using PowerShell**
>
> Install the latest version of the Azure AD PowerShell for Graph module
> (AzureADPreview). (If you need detailed steps, the quickstart for
> adding a guest user includes the section Install the latest
> AzureADPreview module.)

Source :

[MS docs - Configure direct federation in azure ad using powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/direct-federation#to-configure-direct-federation-in-azure-ad-using-powershell)